# Can I change the speed of light in vacuum?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, black-holes, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

General theory of relativity proved that gravity does attract light ( photons ), what if I project a beam of light radially towards a black holes will it increases it's speed or not?

Answer (score -2):

A gravitational source will bend the path of the photons, but it doesn't change its speed. So even if you shine it right at a black hole, its speed will remain c.

Comment: This isn't true. See for example the two questions linked as duplicates that explain how and why gravitational fields **do** change the speed of light.